# How to append MD5 checksum of email content in bash?

Tags: bash, email

I found some lines of output missing from an auto-generated email notification that was dispatched via cron. Having confirmed that there is no AVC error, I want to find out if the integrity of my email was compromised during transit by appending an MD5 checksum of the email content. I have the following script that will generate the email:

```
{
  echo -e "\nUptime";
  uptime;

  last -x --since yesterday;
} | mail -s "Info" user
```

I understand I can do the following to get the MD5 checksum separately:

```
{
  echo -e "\nUptime";
  uptime;

  last -x --since yesterday;
} | openssl md5
```

But how do I combine the checksum with the email content together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an MD5 checksum specifically, you could pipe the content to a file and checksum that, then pipe the file and the checksum (with a delimiter) to mail.

### Using MD5

If you want to use an MD5 sum, you could edit your script to the following which will write to a temporary file, generate the checksum, append it, then send the mail.

```
#!/bin/sh

outfile=$(mktemp)
echo -e "\nUptime"                                    > $outfile 2>&1
uptime                                               >> $outfile  2>&1
last -x --since yesterday                            >> $outfile  2>&1

md5=$(md5sum $outfile | cut -f1 -d' ')
echo-e  "\n==============================\n${md5}\n" >> $outfile 2>&1
cat $outfile | mail -s "Info" user

rm $outfile  # don't forget this - clean up your /tmp!
```

This will capture all the STDERR and STDOUT messages into the logfile and email it to you with the MD5 checksum added to the bottom, so you could put the output back into a file and re-checksum it to make sure it matches.

### Using GPG

Alternatively, you could create (or use an existing) a GPG key that you can use to sign messages coming from your server. Given this will be set up to sign messages in an automated fashion, I would strongly recommend not using this key for anything that you need to keep secure or need to have high trust in, as should your machine be breached, this key will be compromised.

The easiest way to do this would be to generate a GPG key with `gpg --gen-key` on the server (or whatever it is). Most of the details don't matter, but one that does is the passphrase. With this, you can:

- Set a blank passphrase (**not recommended** - never create no-pass keys)
- Set passphrase and save to restricted file (`chmod 400`)
- Set passphrase and pass it in the GPG command

For this example, I will show a key that does have a passphrase that has been added to a file with suitable permissions. Create your key and set up the passphrase as follows:

```
~ » gpg --gen-key
# enter in details for key
    ...
    pub   2048R/B44FD582 2015-02-28 [expires: 2015-03-01]
          Key fingerprint = CFAD 2D53 BB7F CA22 147C  9300 E858 EE8A B44F D582
    uid                  mytestkey (This is my key) <root@myserver.net>
    sub   2048R/D3AEDE76 2015-02-28 [expires: 2015-03-01]

~ » echo -n 'mypassphrase' > ~/.ssh/gpgsignkey
~ » chmod 400 ~/.ssh/gpgsignkey
~ » gpg -a --export root@myserver.net > myserver.key.asc
```

By now you will have a key on your server that can be used for signing, with the passphrase in a restricted file in a secure location (~/.ssh is kept pretty tight), and you have the public key in `myserver.key.asc` that you can import on your local machine in order to verify the received message.

You can then modify your cron job to run a script that executes your command, then pipes the output through gpg to sign the message on its way to your mail server.

```
#!/bin/sh

outfile=$(mktemp)
echo -e "\nUptime"                                    > $outfile 2>&1
uptime                                               >> $outfile  2>&1
last -x --since yesterday                            >> $outfile  2>&1

cat $outfile | gpg --clearsign -u signkey@my-server.net --passphrase-file /root/.ssh/gpgsignkey | mail -s "Info" user

rm $outfile
```

You can then import the public key into your E-Mail client (provided it supports it) or other key-verification mechanism, and authenticate that the message you received was indeed the message that was sent.

Comment: Instead of using a temp file, I output it into a variable. Nevertheless, thanks for your help :)